# How to write this SQL query with Yii Query Builder

Tags: mysql, yii, yii2, query-builder

I have this SQL query which is doing what I want:

```
SELECT `Table1`.* FROM `Table1` 
LEFT JOIN `Table2` ON `Table1`.`idTable2` = `Table2`.`id` 
WHERE (`Table1`.`idOwner`=156 AND `Table2`.`enabled`=1 AND day(Table2.creationDate) <= 5 AND date_format(Table2.creationDate, '%Y-%m') = '2022-12') 
OR (`Table1`.`idOwner`=156 AND `Table2`.`enabled`=1 AND date_format(Table2.creationDate, '%Y-%m') != '2023-01' AND date_format(Table2.creationDate, '%Y-%m') != '2022-12')
```

I tried replicating it as a Yii Query Builder like that:

```
Table1::find()
   ->joinWith(['table2'])
   ->where(['Table1.idOwner' => $idOwner, 'Table2.enabled' => 1])
   ->andWhere(['<=', 'day(Table2.creationDate)', $expirationDay])
   ->andWhere(['=', "date_format(Table2.creationDate, '%Y-%m')", $previousExpirationMonthYear])
   ->orWhere(['Table1.idOwner' => $idOwner, 'Table2.enabled' => 1])
   ->andWhere(['!=', "date_format(Table2.creationDate, '%Y-%m')", $currentExpirationMonthYear])
   ->andWhere(['!=', "date_format(Table2.creationDate, '%Y-%m')", $previousExpirationMonthYear])
   ->all();
```

But I printed the SQL this Query Builder generates with `getRawSql()` and it returns in this strange way:

```
SELECT `Table1`.* FROM `Table1` 
LEFT JOIN `Table2` ON `Table1`.`idTable2` = `Table2`.`id` 
WHERE (((((((`Table1`.`idOwner`=156) 
AND (`Table2`.`enabled`=1)) 
AND (day(Table2.creationDate) <= 5)) 
AND (date_format(Table2.creationDate, '%Y-%m') = '2022-12')) 
OR ((`Table1`.`idOwner`=156) 
AND (`Table2`.`enabled`=1))) 
AND (date_format(Table2.creationDate, '%Y-%m') != '2023-01')) 
AND (date_format(Table2.creationDate, '%Y-%m') != '2022-12')) 
AND (`Table1`.`idOwner`='156')
```

Sorry if its difficult to read it that way.

Can anyone help me to make the Query Builder like the way I want? I would be very appreciated

Comment: Did you try this yii query in the sql ide and check if that produce the same result or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you use `andWhere()` or `orWhere()` the query builder takes existing conditions and do something like this:

> (existing conditions) AND (new conditions)

or

> (existing conditions) OR (new conditions)

respectively.

So if you already have some complex condition and then you try to call

```
orWhere(new condition 1)
->andWhere(new condition 2)
```

You will get

> ((complex condition) OR (new condition 1)) AND (new condition 2).

But in your case you need to get something like:

> (complex condition 1) OR (complex condition 2)

To get something like that you can build the first complex condition same way but you have to build second condition in one `orWhere()` call. Or to make it more readable you can build both complex conditions each in single call:

```php
Table1::find()
    ->joinWith(['table2'])
    ->where([
        'AND',
        ['Table1.idOwner' => $idOwner, 'Table2.enabled' => 1],
        ['<=', 'day(Table2.creationDate)', $expirationDay],
        ['=', "date_format(Table2.creationDate, '%Y-%m')", $previousExpirationMonthYear]
    ])->orWhere([
        'AND',
        ['Table1.idOwner' => $idOwner, 'Table2.enabled' => 1],
        ['!=', "date_format(Table2.creationDate, '%Y-%m')", $currentExpirationMonthYear],
        ['!=', "date_format(Table2.creationDate, '%Y-%m')", $previousExpirationMonthYear]
    ])->all();
```